# how to set input type checkbox border-right?

Tags: html, css

I need to set input type checkbox right side padding `10px` and `border-right:1px solid #000`. I am trying this but the checkbox is not taking the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
   border-right:1px solid #000;
   padding-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't restyle the appearance of a check box. its fixed in the browser like radio buttons.

you could try http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox/ 

 That should give you the answers to styling a checkbox in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

`Padding` is inside the element, if you want a 10px right side spacing instead use `margin-right`

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
   border-right:1px solid #000; // dont know what use is this to the OP
   margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi here am using border but that's not taking

Comment: Border wont work for checkbox. The browsers default styles will always override it.